# How to insert lists to a table without repeating them if they already exist (Using Spring and Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, list, hibernate

first of all, I'd like to point out I'm new to Spring and Hibernate.

I've been trying to connect Hibernate with MySQL (using Spring Data), which I've done successfuly, however, when I try to do an insert I can't get it to do what I want.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a User class, with an ArrayList that contains their preferred coding languages. 
For example:

- User 1: C, Java, C++
- User 2: Python, Java, C++

However, I've noticed that Hibernate will create a new row in the "Languages" table even if it's already there. I also want to keep the "id" as a primary key and as a numeric value.

The following is how it currently inserts the languages to the table:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  2 | C      |
|  3 | Java   |
|  4 | C++    |
|  6 | Python |
|  7 | Java   |
|  8 | C++    |
+----+--------+
```

This is how I want them:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  2 | C      |
|  3 | Java   |
|  4 | C++    |
|  6 | Python |
+----+--------+
```

I've tried different methods, but it's always repeating the values...

This is my user class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String username;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Language> languages;

    ...
}
```

And this is my Language class:

```
@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

This is how I'm adding the languages to each user (it's just a test, not final code):

```
ArrayList<Language> languages = new ArrayList<>();
languages.add(new Language("C"));
languages.add(new Language("Java"));
languages.add(new Language("C++"));
Image image = null;
User admin = new User("iscle", "albertiscle9@gmail.com", "Test_Password", languages, image);
userRepository.save(admin);

ArrayList<Language> languages2 = new ArrayList<>();
languages2.add(new Language("Python"));
languages2.add(new Language("Java"));
languages2.add(new Language("C++"));
Image image2 = null;
User admin2 = new User("iscle", "albertiscle9@gmail.com", "Test_Password", languages2, image2);
userRepository.save(admin2);
```

Comment: As far as I see this is not a _one-to-many_ but a _many-to-many_ relationship. You should change accordingly ...

Comment: In your service, before actually updating, check which `Language`s already exist and replace the ones that exist with the actual DB version.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Maybe the problem is how I'm "creating" the Language instances. I've edited the post to reflect how I'm doing it. Normally, when working with a database manually what I would do is insert all the possible languages into the "Language" table, and then just do a query to find it's ID, but I thought it was possible to just create a new instance every time and then let Hibernate handle it. I guess I was wrong? Would the best way to approach this be to just create the entries first and then just select the apropiate ID?

Thanks again :)

Answer (score -2):

make attribute name (Languages) "UNIQUE"; then you ensure that there will be no duplicate

Comment: That's not enough!

Comment: This will only lead to exceptions on insert.